# regular expression multiple matches

Tags: regex, rsyslog

For reference, this is the regex tester I am using:

http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/

How can I modify this regular expression:

```
[^;]+
```

to receive multiple sub-matches for the following test string:

```
;first;second;third;fourth;fifth and sixth;seventh;
```

I currently only receive one sub-match:

```
first
```

Basically I want each sub-match to consist of the content between `;` characters, I am hoping for a sub-match list like this:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth and sixth
seventh
```

Comment: Usually you need to use a modifier to match several instances. In many languages it's `g`. In PHP you basically use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`. I think the answer to your problem should be somewhere in the docs.

Comment: @HamZa I believe I am using that - note on the linked tester website the field "Submatch to Use" the default is "0 (All)". Are those not the same thing?

Comment: It's referring to group 0. Try for example this regex `([^;])[^;]+` and check group 1. You will notice that the output is `f` from `first`. My intuition says that the current behaviour is by design. Although I can't back this up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following information given in the comments I discovered that the reason I can't get more than one sub-match is that I need to specify the global modifier - and I can't seem to figure out how to do that in the [ryslog regex tester](http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/) I am using.

However, this did lead me to solve my problem in a slightly different manner. I came up with this regular expression which still only gives one match, but the number near the end acts as the index for the desired match, so for example:

```
(?:;([^;]+)){5}
```

matches this from my test string in the question:

```
fifth and sixth
```

While this solution allows me to achieve what I wanted - though in a different manner - the true answer to my question is found in HamZa's comments. More specifically:

> How can I modify the regular expression to receive multiple
>   sub-matches?

The answer is, you *can't modify the regular expression itself* in order to get multiple sub-matches. Setting the global modifier is required in order to do that.

Based on this information I have posted [a new question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/676448/rsyslog-regex-global-modifier) targeted specifically to the rsyslog regular expression system.