# issu with regxp rsyslog

Tags: regex, rsyslog

i have this logs

```
**[06/Aug/2016: 11:47:28 +0200]** [ Warning. Match of "rx \\.(jpg)$" against "REQUEST_FILENAME" required. [file "/mod_security2/modsecurity.conf"] [line "29"] [id "980"] **[msg "USER_ACTIONS_TRACKING (tablecolspan=2&CSRF_TOKEN=-4492965027555802&accessType="]**
```

ineed to extract only this two field `[06/Aug/2016: 11:47:28 +0200]` and `[msg.....]`
the new line of log will be date +msg

i used this rules `\[.*\+/d{4}\]\[(msg).*\]` but it dosent work.
can you help me please
thanks in advance

Comment: Try [`\[[^\]\[]*\+\d{4}\]|\[msg[^\]\[]*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/ifD4b7/1)

Comment: i used this website http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/ and it dosent work

Comment: Yes, because that is POSIX ERE. Try `\[[^][]*[+][0-9]{4}]|\[msg[^][]*]`. Not sure, but you might need to split the regex and use `\[[^][]*[+][0-9]{4}]` and `\[msg[^][]*]` separately.

Comment: how can i do it separately? because i will send tis line of logs to other file log

Comment: No idea how to make this fetch multiple matches, nor access 2 captured values in 1 match. See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111248/regular-expression-multiple-matches thread.

Comment: have you please other solution than regexp?                                                                                                         to send  line logs withe these two values in one match in real time  to other file log